# Complexity analysis of filter() with a lambda function

Tags: python, functional-programming, time-complexity

Given two lists, `list1` and `list2`

```
list3 = filter(lambda x: x in list1,list2)
```

This returns the intersection of the two lists.

How can I find the complexity of this algorithm? I have found out that the time complexity of `x in list1` is [**O(n)**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) where n is number of elements in the list, but how about the `filter`?

Comment: Do you know how to analyze computational complexity in general? If not, go learn to do that. If you do, what specific difficulties are you having with this exercise?

Answer (score 12):

Your code does `O(len(list1) * len(list2))` comparison operations for elements.

- Your lambda function is executed `O(len(list2))` times, once per each element filtered. [See documentation for `filter` in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) ([Python 2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)):

  > `filter(function, iterable)`
  >
  > Construct an `iterator` from **those elements of `iterable` for which function returns true**. `iterable` may be either a sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator

  (emphasis mine)

  Clearly the function is called at least 1 time for each (distinct) element in iterable - knowing when not to need call it would mean also solving [the Halting problem in general case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which not even the Python core developers are yet to solve ;-). In practice in CPython 3 the [`filter` builtin](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/eca51493c770/Python/bltinmodule.c#l380) creates an iterator which when [advanced](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/eca51493c770/Python/bltinmodule.c#l428), executes the function once for each element (distinct or not) in the iteration order.
- The [`x in list1`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) does `O(len(list1))` comparisons in average and worst case, as documented.

---

To speed it up, use a `set`; also you do not need a lambda function at all (use `__contains__` magic method)

```
list3 = filter(set(list1).__contains__, list2)
```

This builds a `set` of the `list1` once in `O(len(list1))` time and runs the filter against it with `O(len(list2))` average complexity for `O(len(list1) + len(list2))`

---

If the ordering of elements of `list2` *does not matter* then you can also do

```
set(list1).intersection(list2)
```

which should have lower constants than doing the `filter` above; and for really fast code, you should order the lists so that the *smaller* is turned into a set (since both intersection and set building have documented average complexity of `O(n)`, but set building most probably will have larger constants due to resizing the `set`, thus it will make sense to build the set from the smaller to decrease the weight of these constants):

```
smaller, larger = sorted([list1, list2], key=len)
result = set(smaller).intersection(larger)
```

---

Notice that Python 2 and 3 differ from each other. `filter` in Python 3 returns a generator, and the actual running time depends on the number of elements consumed from the resulting generator, whereas in Python 2 a list will be generated upfront, which might be more costly if you need only the first values.

Comment: How do you know the `filter` function's time complexity? Didn't manage to find it here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @Controll: We know how it works - it iterates through the list, calling the given function on every element of the list to decide whether to keep that element in the new list - and that's enough to compute its complexity.

Comment: Of course not. But that is how it works, the function is executed once per each element consumed from the argument.

Comment: Is there any way to verify that this is the correct complexity analysis, some library which does that ?

Comment: use `timeit.timeit` with different random inputs.